# What WPF control suits to simulate MS Excel type of sheet filtering in a dialog table?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Requirements:

1. The rows must be grouped to groups
2. There will be subtotal rows for these groups = header rows that not in datasource for actual data rows.
3. Sorting and filtering should be so that rows stay under their groups/headers
4. Every column can be used for sorting and filtering
5. Columns can be added and deleted
6. Filtering is like in Excel -> by many columns and many values for each column can be chosen as filter criteria.
7. Rows filtered out are not calculated in subtotal rows.
8. Possibly other non-data rows can be in table and naturally they are not subject to subtotal calculation / filtering.

I specially want to know is there some kind of support for filtering like this: http://cybersavvyservices.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/excel-filter-drop-down.png

Comment: @marc_s: how can I ask this question in better way?

Comment: A Google search on .NET WPF Excel Control found several.  It is not clear how that filter support sample applies.

Comment: thanks a lot. gotta check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding 2nd answer might result million down votes but gotta add it 'cause my previous answer does not seem to make sense.

I found an article that describes more or less the requirements stated in my orig. question:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126.aspx

Requirement:

1. -> article explains this
2. -> these can be added to group header by making it more complex. sums of the columns can be fetched like in article the row sum
3. -> default functionality
4. -> sorting works for all columns in article. filtering example can be extended
5. -> this has to be implemented. column headers can have controls for hiding a column (see my other answer to my own question in [Is it possible to hide columns in WPF DataGrid when defined and bound with CollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605910/is-it-possible-to-hide-columns-in-wpf-datagrid-when-defined-and-bound-with-colle))
6. -> implement popup for columnheader and dynamically fill it with values in that column
7. -> easy to implement with a converter and binding of the ui element that shows the values in group header.
8. -> it can be added to bound datasource as extra row or the data can be shown in groupheader if it's only little data for each groups.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that DataGridView might be the control. Semi-Excel-filtering is not supported but can be implemented with

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480727.aspx

However the method described in the article is not perfect:

- It relies in bound data source which might have problems when i'm having rows not part of the data source.
- It seems that choosing filtering values support only single select.
- Grouping the actual data rows under the non-data header rows is completely unclear
- Sorting and filtering functionality with the non-data header rows could be a problem

However that's maybe a starting point because a ready made functionality does not exist.